# How to randomly generate objects from multiple arrays with user input in PHP?

Tags: php, html

I am attempting to create a generater where the user inputs how many items to generate. For each time, a number from 1 to 100 is generated. Depending on the result, an item is randomly selected from one of three arrays. It should loop as needed and then display the results. I have partial code below as I tried to follow the logic.

```
<form action='random.php' method='POST' id='random'>
   <table class='table table-responsive'>
     <tr>
        <td>Number of items: </td>
        <td><input type='text' name='randitem'></td>
        <td><button type="submit"Generate</button>
        </td>
     </tr>
   </table>
<?php

$roll = rand(1, 100);

    if $roll < 50

        $commonItem = array(citem1, citem2, citem3);

    if $roll => 50 and < 95

        $uncommonItem = array(uitem1, uitem2, uitem3);

    if $roll => 95

        $rareItem = array(ritem1, ritem2, ritem3);
?>
```

Comment: Your PHP code is invalid for a number of reasons. Is that supposed to be pseudocode or are you trying to write code that will actually compile? The if statement syntax is off and those double arrow `=>` operators won't work in a conditional statement. I'm assuming you mean `>=` for greater than or equal.

Comment: It's pseudocode. The goal is, for an example, the user inputs the number of items to be generated. Let's say the user inputs 3. They click generate. Three percentages are generated. If 1 to 50 percent is generated, then an item from the Common list is randomly chosen. If the percentage is 51 to 94 then an item from the Uncommon list is randomly selected. If the percentage is 95 to 100 then an item from the rare list is randomly selected. Then the results of the 3 items is displayed to the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an idea, where you can randomly choose an item from each array based on which array to choose from (also random, per your sample code):

```
<?php
    $commonItems = array('citem1', 'citem2', 'citem3');
    $uncommonItems = array('uitem1', 'uitem2', 'uitem3');
    $rareItems = array('ritem1', 'ritem2', 'ritem3');
    $roll = rand(1,100);

    if ($roll < 50) {

         $size = count($commonItems) - 1;
         $index = rand(0,$size); 
         $item = $commonItems[$index];

    } elseif ($roll >= 50 && $roll < 95) {

         $size = count($uncommonItems) - 1;
         $index = rand(0,$size); 
         $item = $uncommonItems[$index];

    } else {

         $size = count($rareItems) - 1;
         $index = rand(0,$size); 
         $item = $rareItems[$index];

    }

    echo $item;
?>
```

Here's a refactored version with a function that handles the repetitive functionality in the if statements:

```
<?php
    $commonItems = array('citem1', 'citem2', 'citem3');
    $uncommonItems = array('uitem1', 'uitem2', 'uitem3');
    $rareItems = array('ritem1', 'ritem2', 'ritem3');

    function getItem($itemArray) {    
         $size = count($itemArray) - 1;
         $index = rand(0,$size); 
         return $itemArray[$index];    
    }

    $roll = rand(1,100);
    if ($roll < 50) {
        $item = getItem[$commonItems];
    } elseif ($roll >= 50 && $roll < 95) {
        $item = getItem[$uncommonItems];
    } else {
        $item = getItem[$rareItems];
    }

    echo $item;
?>
```

**EDIT: I missed the part about how you input a number of items, so here's that**

```
    // Check to see if form was submitted with something in randitem
    if (isset($_POST['randitem'])) {

        $commonItems = array('citem1', 'citem2', 'citem3');
        $uncommonItems = array('uitem1', 'uitem2', 'uitem3');
        $rareItems = array('ritem1', 'ritem2', 'ritem3');

        function getItem($itemArray) {    
            $size = count($itemArray) - 1;
            $index = rand(0,$size); 
            return $itemArray[$index];    
        }

        // loop number of times set in form
        foreach ($i = 0; $i < $_POST['randitem']; $i++) {

            $roll = rand(1,100);
            if ($roll < 50) {
                $item = getItem[$commonItems];
            } elseif ($roll >= 50 && $roll < 95) {
                $item = getItem[$uncommonItems];
            } else {
                $item = getItem[$rareItems];
            }

            echo $item . "<br>"; // will print each item on its own line
        }
    }
?>
```

Note: this will do nothing if the form is submitted without a number, so consider changing the input type to "number" or doing some other validation to the form to ensure that only a number is sent to the PHP